# Is solve before needed with dist?

Tags: system-verilog

Section 18.5.10 in the IEEE Std 1800-2017 has the following example to illustrate why we need `solve` `before`:

```
rand bit s;
rand bit [31:0] d;
constraint c { s -> d == 0; }
```

Do the following 2 options still require `solve` `before`?

A.

```
rand bit s;
rand bit [31:0] d;
constraint c1 { d < 1000; }
constraint c2 { if ( s == 1 ) d == 0; }
```

B.

```
rand bit s;
rand bit [31:0] d;
constraint c1 { d < 1000;
                if ( s == 1 ) d == 0;
              }
constraint c2 { s dist { 0 :/ 95, 1 :/ 5 }; }
```

A naive reading of all the above would assume a 50% (5% for option B) chance of choosing `s` as 1, whereas the IEEE standard says you need a `solve s before d` constraint in the first example to get the 50% chance.

Do A and B need a `solve before` to get the expected 50%/5% chance of `s` being 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A would give you a 0.0999% chance of `s` being 1 without the `solve s before d` construct. (s is 1'b1 in only 1 in 1001 solutions).

Option B would give you a 5% chance of `s` being 1 regardless of having the `solve s before d` construct. The `dist` constraint implies an ordering in picking values within the solution space, so adding the `solve before` construct would be redundant.